# ajax upload image errorr C://fakepath

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

hi dears i have problem with save data from ajax

this is my html code

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
    <input type="file" name="fuUpload" id="fuUpload" multiple="multiple" />
    <input name="txtName" type="text" id="txtName" />
    <input type="submit" name="btnSave" value="Save" id="btnSave" />
</div>
</form>
```

and my jquery code

```
 $(function () {
        $('#btnSave').on("click", function () {
            var files = new Array();
           
            for (var i = 0; i < $("#fuUpload").prop("files").length; i++) {
                var file = {};
                file.Name = $("#fuUpload").prop("files")[i].name;
                file.Path = $("#fuUpload").val().split(', ')[i];
                files.push(file);
            }
            var name = $('#txtName').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/Save",
                data: '{files:' + JSON.stringify(files) + ',name:"' + name + '"}',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (r) {
                    alert(r.d);
                },
                error: function (r) {
                    alert(r.responseText);
                }
            })
            return false;
        });
    });
```

in server side

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static void Save(List<FileDetails> files, string name)
    {
     
    
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(files[i].Path, FileMode.Open);
            var fileStream = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + files[i].Name), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            fileStream.Dispose();
            SaveDetails(name, HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + files[i].Name), files[i].Name);
        }
     
    }
```

i have this error : for this line
FileStream stream = new FileStream(files[i].Path, FileMode.Open);
error : [System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\fakepath\pp.jpg'.']
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0f89.png)
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\fakepath\pp.jpg'.'

Comment: Probably the IIS (the user the application pool uses) has not permissions on that path

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directorynotfoundexception?view=net-5.0